# How to remove a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, github-api

I can't see a command to remove a GitHub repository using CLI.

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not implemented... Now you can do this

```
Usage:  gh repo <command> [flags]

Available commands:
  clone
  create
  fork
  view
```